# Not able to save data(drop down values) to DB in symfony2 while uing ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have made a registration page, in which a user has to enter the country details. user will enter the country using dropdown which will get the states dropdown list using ajax and same goes for cities list.
i am getting the lists but when i am trying to save the form ,it says invalid values on city and state field.
Please somebody help me. Thanks. 
Here is my controller

```
public function getStateAction(Request $request)
    {               
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $data = $request->request->all();   

            $countryId = $data['id'];
            $repository = $em->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:State');
            $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
            $query->where('p.countryId ='.$countryId);
            $query->orderBy('p.stateName', 'ASC');
            $stateList = $query->getQuery('p')->getResult();
            $html='';

            foreach($stateList as $list){
                $html .="<option value=".$list->getId()." >".$list->getStateName()."</option>";
            }
            return new JsonResponse( $html );       
    }

    public function getCityAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $data = $request->request->all();   

            $stateId = $data['id'];
            $repository = $em->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:City');
            $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
            $query->where('p.stateId ='.$stateId);
            $query->orderBy('p.cityName', 'ASC');
            $stateList = $query->getQuery('p')->getResult();
            $html='';
            foreach($stateList as $list){
                $html .="<option value=".$list->getId()." >".$list->getCityName()."</option>";
            }
            return new JsonResponse( $html );

    }
```

This is my Ajax.

```
{% block javascripts %}   
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){      $("#fos_user_registration_form_country_id").change(function(){
                    $("#fos_user_registration_form_state_id").empty();
                    var countryId = $(this).val();  

                    if(countryId!=0){
                      $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "{{ path('fos_user_registration_country') }}",
                         data: {id: countryId},
                         cache: false,
                         success: function(result){

                           $("#fos_user_registration_form_state_id").append(result);

                         }
                       });
                    }
                    });
                    $("#fos_user_registration_form_state_id").change(function(){
                     var stateId = $(this).val();
                     $("#fos_user_registration_form_city_id").empty();
                     if(stateId!=0){
                     $.ajax ({
                       type:"POST",
                       url: "{{ path('fos_user_registration_state') }}",
                       data: {id: stateId}, 
                       cache: false,
                       success: function(result){
                       $("#fos_user_registration_form_city_id").append(result);
                         }
                       });
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Please select country');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        });
        </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

I have made a registration form, whenever i try to save the details of a person then i get an error that the `city_id` and `state_id` have **invalid value**.

Comment: Just clarifying, is the data type of city_id is **IntegerType**?

You may need to typecast the **String** value you received from the ajax request to Integer.

Comment: yeah @WillyPt the value of city_id and stae_id is integer.

Comment: How does the definition of your form type look like for which you load the additional data?

Comment: This is the definition of my form type  @xabbuh
$builder->add('state_id', 'choice', array('label'=>false,'required'=>false,
                'choices' => array(
                    "" => 'Select State',
     

                )));

$builder->add('city_id', 'choice', array('label'=>false,'required'=>false,
                'choices' => array(
                    "" => 'Select City',
                    
                )));

Comment: The issue with that is that the Symfony Form component does not know which choices are valid (only the choices in your front-end are populated, the PHP backend only knows the empty placeholder options, by the way, you should use the `placeholder` option for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the stateId and cityId were not going to db. The stateId and cityId are the foreign keys associated with different tables.I was able to overcome this issue by the following code.

```
public function saveAction(Request $request)
        {           

                $data = $request->request->all();   


                $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $user = $userManager->createUser();

                $countryId =$data['fos_user_registration_form']['country_id'];
                $stateId =$data['fos_user_registration_form']['state_id'];
                $cityId =$data['fos_user_registration_form']['city_id'];

                $country= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:Country')->find($countryId);
                $user->setCountry($country);

                $state= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:State')->find($stateId);
                $user->setState($state);

                $city= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:City')->find($cityId);
                $user->setCity($city);

     /.../
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do to solve the problem is to just populate the state type with the full list of available states (if I understand your current solution correctly, this already happens in AJAX so there's not a real difference for the user). The city list should still be fetched through an AJAX request depending on the selected state.

However, when the form is submitted your need to listen to the form's `PRE_SUBMIT` event, check the selected value of the state type and populate the city choices based on that value. This way the Form component will be able to properly validate the selected city value.

You can find a similar example can be found in the cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: i was able to save the data using serialize function  i used serialize function to save the form data @xabbuh